# run java program from cmd with class imports from jar files

Tags: java, jar, import, cmd

Hey community I have this rookie problem so if anyone could help that would be great :)

So here it goes...

I'm trying to test the stanford NLP parser by trying to run the java demo file which is included in the file you can download from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20.zip)

My problem is probably on the imports of the classes included in the .jar files..I tried the solutions on some other stackoverflow threads such as doing
`javac -cp "jar/path/number/1";"jar/path/number/2" ParserDemo.java`
but the
`java -cp "jar/path/number/1";"jar/path/number/2" ParserDemo`
command didn't work.

I also tried to extract every jar file in a common folder but then I got the bad class file error..

So what's the move here? How can I solve this ?

P.S. please don't propose as a solution to use the online version of the parser.

EDIT: I'm using Windows 8.1 just in case somebody needs to know

Comment: Did `javac` work? Did it create a file called ParseDemo.class?

Comment: How exactly does your command look like? Did you include jar files names or maybe added `jars/location/*` wildcard to include all jar files from directory. Also what do you mean by "command didn't work"? Do you get any error?

Comment: Maybe this will interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: @mlk yeah it did, I had done the PATH modification needed..

Comment: @Pshemo I included the jar files by name like "jarsFolder/jarFile.jar" and after the java command I get the error "Could not find or load main class ParserDemo" however a .class file exists

Comment: Is "." included in your path? Try `java -cp ".;jar/path/number/1";"jar/path/number/2" ParserDemo`

Comment: Where is `ParserDemo` class located (does it have package declaration?) and from which location you are running your command?

Comment: @Pshemo the ParserDemo class is in a folder on my desktop and I'm running the command from that same location, I updated the question as something proposed worked, I don't know if it's a coincidence if it's not too much trouble you can check it :)

Comment: `.` represents current location and it should also be included in class path. Normally we include it in CLASSPATH system variable to avoid repetition of `-cp .` in command, so if you didn't set it there you need to include it in your command. Anyway you should not post solution as part of question but post it as separate answer (there should be blue button under your post with text similar to "answer your question").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it was posted as a comment and I don't know if it would be visible for future reference I'm gonna write the solution down here as proposed by the user mlk

I fixed my java command to `java -cp ".;jar/path/number/1";"jar/path/number/2" ParserDemo` and it worked perfectly!

This is because the current folder (`.`) was not included in the classpath so Java could not see the `ParserDemo.class` file.

Comment: Glad that worked. Please mark this answer as "correct"

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me (it says I can accept it in 23 hours) :)